# Make NA values in table just blank cells when using cell_spec in kableExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

Following on from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52193105/7347699), I am using the `cell_spec` function from **kableExtra** to change the background color of cells within a table. How can you remove the NA text and color the background white for the NA cells so that an NA appears just as a blank cell?

Below is my example table with the NA cells. In real life there is a dynamic number of columns with various number of NAs in each column.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

set.seed(2)
d <- data_frame(group = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace=TRUE), cat1=runif(10, 0, 100), cat2=runif(10, 0, 100))
d[3:5,2:3] <- NA

# Functions used to create color palette
max.val <- max(d[ , sapply(d, is.numeric)], na.rm=TRUE)
pal.fnc <- colorRamp(c("red", "yellow", "green"))

d <- d %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) {
  cell_spec(round(x,1), "latex", bold = F, color=grey(.3),
            background = rgb(pal.fnc(x/max.val) %>% replace(., is.na(.), 200), maxColorValue=255))
})   
```

```{r table, echo = FALSE}
kable(d,
      linesep = "",
      booktabs = T, 
      escape = F )
```
````

[image]

Comment: It is not necessary to load all the additional LaTeX packages for **kableExtra** to work if you are using the latest version :) https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can control **knitr** `options(knitr.kable.NA = '')` to suppress NAs, however this is not working here as you are overwriting the NAs with the value as `\\cellcolor[HTML]{C8C8C8}{\\textcolor[HTML]{4D4D4D}{NA}}"`.

To make the `options(knitr.kable.NA = '')` line work, we will have to control the `cell_spec` function only run on non NA values, and prevent it from adding the extra HTML code to the NA values. We can use `case_when` within **dplyr** to [conditionally mutate the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674628/conditionally-formatting-cells-in-one-column-by-comparing-it-with-the-value-from), so that the NAs are left untouched. To make it easier to read I created a function `colourCell` which is then used within the `mutate_if` statement before creating the table:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

options(knitr.kable.NA = '')

# Create Data
set.seed(2)
d <- data_frame(group = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace=TRUE), cat1=runif(10, 0, 100), cat2=runif(10, 0, 100))
d[3:5,2:3] <- NA

# Functions to format cell
max.val = max(d[ , sapply(d, is.numeric)], na.rm=TRUE)
pal.fnc <- colorRamp(c("red", "yellow", "green"))

colourCell <- function(x) {
  cell_spec(round(x,1), "latex",
            bold = F,
            color=grey(.3),
            background = rgb(pal.fnc(x/max.val) %>% 
                               replace(., is.na(.), 200), maxColorValue=255))
}
```

```{r table, echo = FALSE}
d %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) {
    case_when(!is.na(x) ~ colourCell(x))
})  %>%
  kable(
      linesep = "",
      booktabs = T, 
      escape = F)
```
````

[image]

Comment: options(knitr.kable.NA = '') is necessary. the result witll have NA unless it is there.

Comment: Yeah, that line was included within my answer, but I think I made the intro a bit confusing. Hopefully made things clearer